# Ties to Home Country for Canada Visa Application

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I am not yet married, I work and live in Nigeria as an Engineer. I want to submit an application for a Canadian tourist visa.

I have my own small business too (I run part time) and I work in a small company (full time). I have never been to any nations in the EU or Americas (apparently I do not have anyone there) just Africa here and back home (Ghana and South Africa)

Since I have a registered business in Nigeria, and I have dependent parents, can I submit a visa application on this note, using these things as my standpoint for a visa application?

Comment: Don't know how deep they examine this kind of thing, but it would seem to me the registered business in Nigeria is only helpful if you have employees or can demonstrate an established and viable business with local customers, etc. Unless this is the case, you should probably focus on your salaried work (including all the relevant proof: payslips, bank account statements that show your salary being paid every month, etc.). The dependent parents are probably a plus, but this can be a double-edged sword depending on the exact circumstances.

Comment: yes i have employees. 4 of them of which are paid salaries. its basically a small software company which i run part time (Sell webhosting , Software development and deployment). i am kept on day to day basis of happenings and its registered with corporate affairs commision of my country here. double edged sword? Kindly clarify

Comment: Well then it should be quite easy to prove your ties to your country just with the business (your employees are based in Nigeria and you do have contracts and payslips for them, of course?). The depended parents issue is that it's sometimes difficult to prove, and in the worst case it could show that their "cost" to you means a trip abroad is financially difficult for you (or, alternatively, that you need to get a job in a higher-paying country to support them -- probably not your case here). But again, it all depends on the exact circumstances.

Comment: yes my employees are based here in Nigeria with me. Like i said i have the certificate officially given to me from CAC (corporate affairs commission), and yes they are on contracts with me as well.

Comment: @jcaron u advise i present the payslips and bank statements +  certificate from the government incoporating my company and tax clearances and also bank statememnts for the company as well right?

Comment: @jcaron i missed few things. i present payslips and bank statements from the company which i work with as well as the other documentation (Certificate from CAC and tax clearance) from corporate affairs commision (For my small business )

Comment: Anything that proves your ties to your country and supports any statements you make in your application. But don't forget your own payslips and bank statements and all the rest of the document they ask for, of course.

Comment: You not being married and have no travel history is not a good combination. Not knowing anyone in Canada will HELP with your tourist visa. You can submit an application based on whatever you want, the approval is where they will look at your info. Show them your dependents and round trip ticket will help and not knowing anyone in Canada is good